# Add class to c++ firemonkey project

Tags: mobile, c++builder, firemonkey

I have written a small firemonkey mobile app in C++ XE6 using several forms/units which all attempt to read data from a json feed.
I would like to keep the user details in a separate class to pass in the REST request rather than pass them from form to form.
What is the syntax for creating a static class and, other than including a reference to myclass.h, how does one access it's properties please?

Comment: This is C++ 101 kind of stuff that is not specific to FireMonkey or C++Builder. If you don't know how to define a class in a .h file and then create an instance of that class and share it across multiple units, either as an `extern` or by using pointers, you should stop and re-learn the basics.